# Variance from bootstrap sample

Tags: mathematical-statistics, variance, prediction, bootstrap

For a given set of parameters I get a prediction from a model. Can I bootstrap my data for the given parameters and take the variance of my estimates for the given parameter values to approximate the variance associated with the original prediction. For example,

Given the parameters

$$[ x_1,x_2,…, x_n]$$

I get prediction

$$F([x_1,x_2,…, x_n])=y$$

I bootstrap my data 10,000 times and get 10,000 predictions with parameters

$$[x_1,x_2,…, x_n]$$

$$F_1([x_1,x_2,…, x_n]),…,F_{10000}([x_1,x_2,…, x_n])$$

Will the variance of the distribution of 10,000 bootstrap predictions approximate the variance of

$$F([x_1,x_2,…, x_n])=y$$